# Can't include a virtual navigational property

Tags: c#, linq, include

In my model (auto-generated), I can see:

```
public partial class Order
{
  public System.Guid OrderId { get; set; }
  ...
  public System.Guid ProductId { get; set; }
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try include the product into the returned set (since I'm going to need some values of it later on), there's nothing provided after intellisense.

```
using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
  return context.Orders
    .Include(order=>order.???)
    .Where(order => order.Condition)
    .ToList();
```

I re-generated the model and re-run the T4 scripts. Inclusion of the other entities work as supposed to. Can't see what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your forgot to add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

so you're not able to use the `Include` overload taking an expression as parameter that is provided by the `System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions` class.

Comment: Oh, but I had it, right there. Then I refactored the file to split two classes into each own, separate file. And the stupid donkey poo Resharper didn't bring the stuff over to the new file! Good eye for details, mate. +1!